# Are there any terminal tools to connect iphone in order to execute git commands

Tags: ios, git

how can I use terminal in mac os to connect the iphone, I want to use git commands to see the sha1 value that store in iphone.

Comment: You're trying to see what? Your question is very unclear, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have clone a git on iphone app document, I want to execute git command to see the data, such as "git ls-trees". But I can't find where to type it, how to connect to the iphone and where to input the commands?

Comment: Maybe apple don't support it~~